# What is a regex that will match everything above a specific string?

Tags: php, regex

What is a regex that will match everything in a text above a specific string?

The string is `=============REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE=============` and i want to get all the content above it using **PHP**

**Example text**

```
this is a sample text here i want to match using regex. because it is above the following line 
=============REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE=============
here is below the line
```

**so the regex will return only**

```
this is a sample text here i want to match using regex. because it is above the following line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not rather go about it this way?

```
$input = "this is a sample text here i want to match using regex. because it is above the following line =============REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE============= here is below the line"

$pieces = explode("=============REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE=============", $input);

$above_line = trim($pieces[0]);

$below_line = trim($pieces[1]);
```

Comment: @Dale Yeah, agreed, sorry about that. I will edit my answer into an actual answer when I get a response.

Comment: @villoui Adjusted my answer :)